# How to compile the following bibtex to get the list of publications

Tags: bibtex

I am having the references list as;

```
@article{ahmed2016revisiting,
title={Revisiting double Dirac delta potential},
author={Ahmed, Zafar and Kumar, Sachin and Sharma, Mayank and Sharma, Vibhu},
journal={European Journal of Physics},
volume={37},
number={4},
pages={045406},
year={2016},
publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{kumar2017spectral,
title={Spectral statistics for ensembles of various real random matrices},
author={Kumar, Sachin and Ahmed, Zafar},
journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1704.02715},
year={2017}
}
```

Could Anyone please help me, that How to generate the list out of it.

P.S.: I tried several posts related to that, but didn't get the desired result!

Comment: Without a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/184389), we cannot really help you. Moreover, [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management) tells you how to manage a bibliography with `BibTeX`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 might be an interesting read if you want to know more about BibTeX and why you need to call an external program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a minimal running example you can do the following.

Save the above references in a file, e.g. `mybib.bib`.

In the same directory create a file, e.g. `file.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Now run the following commands from the shell in the directory of your files

```
pdflatex file
bibtex file
pdflatex file
pdflatex file
```

The output will be a file `file.pdf` which displays as

[image: Sample output]